# Check a specific checkbox in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-table

I have a HTML table with a column containing checkboxes. Can anyone please tell me how I can use Javascript to set a checkbox at a specific row index to checked (without using jquery)?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not want to use jQuery? It's dramatically less typing, and simpler to learn/use. These intros are worth your time: [thenewboston.com](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32) and [phpacademy.org](https://phpacademy.org/courses/javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to give each checkbok a specific id. Like that it is easy to check it with javascript.

Probably the best solution is to give it an id that contains either the row number or an unique identifier of the data in the row.

Answer (score 6):

If your checkboxes have unique ids then you can simply do the following:

```
// To check the box with id "check3"
document.getElementById("check3").checked = true;
```

However if you are literally wanting to check it based off its row index in the table then you'll have to first grab the table and drop down to the specific row index from there.

```
// To check the box in row 3 in table with id "mytable" (0-based row index)
// assuming that the checkbox is in the first column, 
// and that it is the first element in that column
document.getElementById("mytable").rows[2].cells[0].children[0].checked = true;
```

Instead of hard-coding the 0's in there you could also loop through the `cells` and `children` arrays explicitly looking for `input` elements of type `checkbox`.  Without actually seeing your code it's hard to give a specific recommendation, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to Check\Uncheck all Checkboxes.

http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/javascript-function-check-uncheck-checkboxes/

The checkboxes should have an ID, then you can grab them with "getElementById()"